# Print just the value of one json key response with python

Tags: python, json, get

I'm new on it all.
I have a url that returns me a token, in a json format. This token changes all the time I call this url. It's something like this:

```
{
"token": {
    "token": "randomtoken",
    "result": 1,
    "resultCode": "2",
    "requestId": "3"
}}
```

I want to print just the result of token key when I call my python code, which is like this:

```
import requests as req

resp = req.get("http://myurl.com.br")

print(resp.text)
```

This python code is returning me the following result:

```
{"token":{"token":"randomtoken","result":1,"resultCode":"2","requestId":"3"}}
```

How can I print just the token key result? Like just:

```
"randomtoken"
```

It's possible?

Comment: `resp.json()['token']['token']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `dict` so you may access it with its keys as string

```
import requests as req

resp = req.get("http://myurl.com.br")
token_key = resp.json()['token']['token']
print(token_key)
```

---

Note that

- `resp.text` returns a string, you would need `json.loads(resp.text)` to get a dict
- `resp.json()` does the loading from the text

Comment: That's it!! Worked for me. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
t = json.loads(resp.text)
print(t["token"]["token"])
```